# Django: Get details of related object

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to list details of an object and details of the related object, via *ForeignKey*. I can accomplish this in the Django shell but fail to understand of how to translate this to *models.py* or *admin.py*

```
l1 = Logins.objects.get(id=1)
l1.Benutzer.Vorname
```

Essential details as follows:
**models.py**

```
class Portalbenutzer(models.Model):
    Vorname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Nachname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nachname

class Logins(models.Model):
    Benutzer = models.ForeignKey(Portalbenutzer)
    Datum = models.DateTimeField('Login-Zeitpunkt')
    URL = models.URLField('URL-Login')
    LoggedOut = models.DateTimeField('Logout-Zeitpunkt')
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**admin.py**

```
class LoginsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['Datum','LoggedOut','Benutzer','URL']

    admin.site.register(Logins, LoginsAdmin)
```

**More specific**: How do I get to list the value of *Vorname*?
Is it (*models.py*) as follows?

```
VName = self.Benutzer.Vorname
```

To list it in admin-area of *Logins* I could than add 'Vname' in *fields*.
**How do I accomplish this?**

Comment: You can use exactly the same code,  Logins.objects.get(id=1).Benuzter.Vorname

Comment: This question is very unclear, not only because it is in German, but because your suggested code does exactly what you require: what is your actual problem?

Comment: @sirlark could you be more specific? Where and how do I use exactly the same could? Adding the shell-syntax in models.py or admin.py (in various ways) does only return errors.

Comment: Then you need to show *exactly* what "various ways" you have tried, and exactly what errors you get. We really can't help you otherwise.

Comment: @d-nnis: Depends on what you are trying to do. Generally, I expect it would be used in views.py, but you've made no mention of that. I'm guessing, since my German is rusty, that what you actually want is to see inline details of related objects in the admin interface. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put Benutzer somewhere in your `__str__` overload for Logins, and add Vorname to the overload of Benutzer.

```
class Portalbenutzer(models.Model):
    Vorname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Nachname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} {}".format(self.Vorname, self.Nachname)

class Logins(models.Model):
    Benutzer = models.ForeignKey(Portalbenutzer)
    Datum = models.DateTimeField('Login-Zeitpunkt')
    URL = models.URLField('URL-Login')
    LoggedOut = models.DateTimeField('Logout-Zeitpunkt')
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({})".format(self.id, self.Benuzter)
```

If you specifically want Benutzer to display only with surnames, but see the first names from the logins view, you can access the attributes of a related Benutzer in the `__str__` overload, just like in the shell

```
class Portalbenutzer(models.Model):
    Vorname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    Nachname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Nachname

class Logins(models.Model):
    Benutzer = models.ForeignKey(Portalbenutzer)
    Datum = models.DateTimeField('Login-Zeitpunkt')
    URL = models.URLField('URL-Login')
    LoggedOut = models.DateTimeField('Logout-Zeitpunkt')
    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ({})".format(self.id, self.Benuzter)
```

Comment: Thanks it is quite close to what I am looking for. Still need to better understand the whole picture.

Answer (score 1):

If I get well what you are trying to do, it looks like this page could help:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline

You'll actually not add 'Vname' in *fields*, but you'll have to make another class herited from *GenericTabularInline* (or a related class, see the doc) that way:

```
class PortalbenutzerInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = Portalbenutzer
```

Then, modify your admin.py that way:

```
class LoginsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['Datum','LoggedOut','Benutzer','URL']
    inline = [PortalbenutzerInline,]

admin.site.register(Logins, LoginsAdmin)
```

This should give you access to fields defined in *Portalbenutzer* while rendering *Logins*. Django documentation will give you some advices to kindly tune it and add only *Vorname* field (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations-in-admin).

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, I implemented it (hopefully correct) to try it out. It is not exactly what I am looking, and yet I do not understand the full scope of the possibility of GenericTabularInline. Basically I want to display a list of the objects joined with the related objects. I guess plunging into the views-section will eventually show what I am looking for.